# OpenCL: maintaining separate version of kernels

Tags: opencl

The [Intel SDK](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/ioclsdk/2013/OG/Keeping_Kernel_Sources_the_Same.htm) says:

> If you need separate versions of kernels, one way to keep the source
>   code base same, is using the preprocessor to create CPU-specific or
>   GPU-specific optimized versions of the kernels. You can run
>   clBuildProgram twice on the same program object, once for CPU with
>   some flag (compiler input) indicating the CPU version, the second time
>   for GPU and corresponding compiler flags. Then, when you create two
>   kernels with clCreateKernel, the runtime has two different versions
>   for each kernel.

Let us say I use `clBuildProgram` twice with flags for CPU and GPU. This will compile two versions of program one optimized for CPU and another optimized for GPU.   But how will I create two kernels now, since there is not CPU/GPU specific option in `clCreateKernel()`?

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of calls to build the kernel for CPU- and GPU devices and obtain the different kernels could look like this:

```
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(...)

clBuildProgram(program, numCpuDevices, cpuDeviceList, cpuOptions, NULL, NULL);
cl_kernel cpuKernel = clCreateKernel(program, ...);

clBuildProgram(program, numGpuDevices, gpuDeviceList, gpuOptions, NULL, NULL);
cl_kernel gpuKernel = clCreateKernel(program, ...);
```

<sub>(Note: I could not test this at the moment. If there's something wrong, I'll delete this answer)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You would create only kernel with the same name. To discriminate between devices you would use the `#ifdef` queries *inside* the kernel, i.e.:

```
kernel void foo(global float *bar)
{
#ifdef HAVE_CPU
    bar[0] = 23.0;
#elif HAVE_GPU
    bar[0] = 42.0;
#endif
}
```

You can obtain this flag by

```
program.build({device}, "-DHAVE_CPU")
```

or `-DHAVE_GPU`. Remark: `-D...` is not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

`clCreateKernel` creates an entry point to a program, and the program has already been compiled for an specific device (CPU or GPU). So, there is nothing that you can do at the create kernel level if the program is already compiled in one or the other way.

By passing different compiled program objects, `clCreateKernel` will create different kernel objects for different devices.

The key to control the GPU/CPU mode is at the `clBuildProgram` step, where a device has to be specified.
Additionally the compilation can be further refined with external defines to disable/enable pieces of code specifically designed for CPU/GPU.